# PostgreSQL- replication server lags behind the master - memory usage too high

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, replication

we have a classic physical replication with primary and secondary nodes. The two nodes are also monitored by software.
There are always lags between the primary server and secondary server when there is a higher load, e.g. when creating a logical dump.

I noticed that the main memory was maximally full and is cached by PostgreSQL. I then worked through the postgresql.conf, and adjusted everything that has to do with the RAM so far:
So that the RAM is neatly divided, I have the following calculation:

total RAM ~ 15 GB = 100%

RAM for PostgreSQL: total RAM * 0.9 = 13.5 GB

shared_buffer: RAM for PostgreSQL * 0.3 ~ = 4GB

temp_buffers: 8MB

work_mem: (RAM for PostgreSQL * 0.25) / (max_connections + superuser_reserved_connections) = 32MB

Session-dependent memory (required memory at full capacity): (temp_buffers + work_mem + Overhead (1MB)) * (max_connections + superuser_reserved_connections) = (8MB + 32MB + 1MB) * (100 + 3) ~ = 4243MB = 4.5 GB

effective_cache_size (rest to get to 90%): 13.5 GB - (4 GB + 4.5GB) ~ = 5GB

After the changes to postgresql.conf, the working memory was roughly as used as calculated.
But when you run pg_dumpall, the memory requirement increases and remains high. With the second pg_dumpall, the demand increases again and remains at the same level. Postgresql caches more and more memory. At some point Ubuntu then begins to swap memory and then the replication server lags.

I could not find out why that is, I would be very happy about your help.

Edit:
When comparing htop and the software that monitors our cluster, I noticed that the software shows the memory usage incorrectly.

[image]

[image]

I think I should check whether the replication server is really lagging behind the primary server, or whether this is just a software bug

Comment: "I noticed that the main memory was maximally full and is cached by PostgreSQL."  How did you notice this?  What does it mean?  Please show us the output you looked at (`top`, `vmstat`, `free`, `ps`, whatever), rather than your interpretation of that output.

Comment: Hi jjanes, Thanks for the comment! I have expanded the question.
How can I check whether the replication server is lagging behind the primary server?